# Adding User Control Dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, dynamic, user-controls

I know this question was asked many times, but still my problem is not solved,

I'm trying to iterate on a list of objects, and fill a template "user control" with that object,
like result list of a search.

in these user controls there is a linkButton which should redirect to another page,
when I click on that linkButton nothing happens, I googled it but no satisfying answer.

here is the code, I'll illustrate with button instead of a user control:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventsArgs e)
{
   for(int i=0;i<10;i=i+1)
   {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.ID = "Button" + i;
        b.Click += new System.EventHAndler(this.Button_OnClick);
        Controls.Add(b);
    }
 base.OnInit(e);
}

private void Button_OnClick(object Sender,System.EventsArgs e)
{
     Response.Redirect("~/Some.aspx");
}

public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    return;
}
```

It never calls the Button_OnClick method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your sample, can you post the actual code?

Comment: I've just edited the code, this is what I'm having now, I want the new buttons to fire event. I'm using VerifyRenderingInServerForm method, otherwise there will be an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button will never fire because is not a child of a server form control.

If there is no form control yet, you need to add it:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
</form>
```

And replace

```
  Controls.Add(b);
```

With

```
  form1.Controls.Add(b);
```

Comment: Where should I place <form id="form1" runat="server"> </form> exactly? after <head runat="server"> or before that?

Comment: It's working :) thanks a lot, I was strugling for three days.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.ID = "Button" + i;
    b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click); 
    Controls.Add(b);
}

void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing this, but it never reaches that method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Page_Init instead of OnInit.

Calling base.OnInit before creating the buttons might also work.